# hibernate error

Tags: java, hibernate

---

Hy again,

Yesterday was working fine and today I receive the following error when I started with the same code in class and hibernate file.
Have anyone some clue what happened?

```
15:56:26 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] (XMLHelper.java:81) - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(4) The content of element type "class" is incomplete, it must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".
null
15:56:26 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] (XMLHelper.java:81) - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(4) The content of element type "class" is incomplete, it must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".
15:56:26 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] (XMLHelper.java:81) - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(13) The element type "hibernate-mapping" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hibernate-mapping>".
Cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [app-data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
15:56:26 ERROR [AWT-EventQueue-0] (XMLHelper.java:81) - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(13) The element type "hibernate-mapping" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hibernate-mapping>".
```

---

I have written the hibernate mapping file for class `Utilizator` that uses the `Utilizatori` table in SQL 2008 and I am getting the following error when the class is called by the application:

```
Cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'utilizatorDAO' defined in class path resource [app-data.xml]: 
    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: 
    Initialization of DAO failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: 
    Utilizatori is not mapped [from Utilizatori where utilizator = ?]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
    Utilizatori is not mapped [from Utilizatori where utilizator = ?]
```

Here is the class code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package domain;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class Utilizator {

    private Long idUtilizator;
    private String utilizator;
    private String parola;
    private String nivelAcces;
    private String nume;
    private String prenume;

    public Utilizator() {

    }

    public Long getIdUtilizator() {
        return idUtilizator;
    }

    public void setIdUtilizator(Long idUtilizator) {
        this.idUtilizator = idUtilizator;
    }

    public String getUtilizator() {
        return utilizator;
    }

    public void setUtilizator(String utilizator) {
        this.utilizator = utilizator;
    }

    public String getParola() {
        return parola;
    }

    public void setParola(String parola) {
        this.parola = parola;
    }

    public String getNivelAcces() {
        return nivelAcces;
    }

    public void setNivelAcces(String nivelAcces) {
        this.nivelAcces = nivelAcces;
    }

    public String getNume() {
        return nume;
    }

    public void setNume(String nume) {
        this.nume = nume;
    }

    public String getPrenume() {
        return prenume;
    }

    public void setPrenume(String prenume) {
        this.prenume = prenume;
    }

}
```

and mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="domain.Utilizator" table="Utilizatori"/>

        <id name="idUtilizator" column="IDUtilizator">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>       

        <property name="utilizator"/>
        <property name="parola"/>
        <property name="nivelAcces"/>
    </class>             
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Please post your mapping file and your code.

Comment: Is the class `Utilizator` or `Utilizatori`? HQL should use the class name.

Comment: Utilizator is the class; Utilizatori is the name of the SQL table

Comment: i`ve added the mapping file and class code.thx

Comment: ... Like I said, the query should use the class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is wrong; it should use the name of the class, not the name of the database table; i.e., use     `Utilizator` not `Utilizatori`.

Comment: If this is the solution you opt for, click the  accept button next to it! :)